# about Java byte type value greater than 256

Tags: java, byte

```
public void demo(byte[] p,byte[] buffer){

SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(p, "HmacSHA1");
int count = 4096;
int num = 1;



Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(signingKey);

while(num < count){
    byte[] sig = new byte[4];
    sig[0] = (byte)num;


    mac.update(buffer,0,buffer.length);
    mac.update(sig,0,4);

    String result = byteArrayToHex(mac.doFinal());

    num ++;
}}
```

if the num value is 256.Will result in incorrect results

what should I do?

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly.

Comment: The data type `byte` holds values from -128 to 127. If you pretend that it's not a signed datatype, you can work with values from 0 to 255 with some extra steps (like doing `&0xff` when you promote to an `int`). But it's impossible for a `byte` to hold the value 256. There are only 256 different values that you can encode with 8 bits, and they are all used by the number range 0-255.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'Java byte type value greater than 256', or 255 or even 127 for that matter. Whatever you are trying to do is impossible, and what you are asking about is non-existent. Surely what you really want to do here is convert the integer `num` into *four* bytes?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for my bad title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Java byte type value greater than 256

Not possible to store values higher than 255.

A [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) in Java is an [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)), [8-bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_computing). This is true of both the [`byte` primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) type and the [`Byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Byte.html) wrapper class.

As a signed value, that means a range of -128 to 127. As an unsigned value, that means a range of 0 to 255. In neither case is there room to represent the number 256 or higher.

See details in [Comment by Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687192/about-java-byte-type-value-greater-than-256/71687632#comment126693206_71687192).

Comment: i known,but the function of mac.update() type must be byte[].

Comment: @ThinkBurp and? that doesn't change anything about what Basil and have said. I think you should describe what you're really trying to do instead of asking how to store a byte with the value 256, which is impossible.